# How to fix context menu handlers?

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, context-menu

I have switchable graphic laptop video card that is controlled by AMD drivers. It provides 2 context menu options to configure grpahic cards. The problem is that after restoring my system these option names turned into question marks:

[image]

It doesn't prevent these menu from working, but looks somewhat annoying issue. I was looking for how these menu items are implemented and found that there are records in the Registry under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers`, but couldn't find out how to fix them.

Comment: There is some doubt about "after restoring my system". Did you uninstall that driver? Do you want remove that context menu completely? Also provide a link for those software(s).

Comment: @Biswario, no, I didn't uninstall the driver. I used system image, the system is configured to create regularly. I don't want to remove anything, the driver works properly and I didn't install anything specific, these menu items are part of the laptop driver itself. The laptop is HP Pavilion dv7 6053er

Comment: @Biswapriyo the driver is Catalyst, but it's not common, since laptop cards tend to be somewhat specific. You can find the laptop driver on HP site

Comment: If you click on it, can you enter in AMD video card management?     Have you reinstalled the AMD driver?

Comment: @Peter.G yes, everything worked, apart from the appearance of the items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a couple of days of going back and forth, I figured out that the problem lies with 'Regional and Language options'. Under the 'Advanced' tab I had English language selected for the programs not supporting Unicode. So, the Catalyst driver was installed for Russian system and presumably didn't have proper resources for English locale. After setting this option to Russian, the problem vanished:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The simplest advice is to repeat the installation of the driver.

This should recreate the context menu entries.